# session become null in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, ienumerable, rotativa

I have following controller , in that controller I created session to save `IENUMERABLE` data-set

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
    {

        IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel = model;

        IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> sample = model.Where.....

        Session["TemplateData"] = newmodel;

        return View(sample);
    }
```

---

**EDIT:**

Create_Brchure View page has href link to call `PrintIndex` method in same class file

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PrintIndex", "Brochure")">Download ViewAsPdf</a>
```

this is `PrintIndex` method

```
    public ActionResult PrintIndex()
    {
        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Create_Brochure_PDF") { FileName = "TestActionAsPdf.pdf" };
    }
```

---

I want to use that session list dataset again in `Create_Brochure_PDF` controller method,so I created here that method

```
    public ActionResult Create_Brochure_PDF()
    {
        IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel = Session["TemplateData"] as IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>;

        IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> samplePDF = newmodel.Where(....

        return View(samplePDF);
    }
```

but in above method I'm getting null `IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel`

**EDIT:**

If I explain this whole scenario

1. `Create_Brochure` controller method has a view ,
2. In that view I have href link to save that `Create_Brochure` view as
   `PDF`
3. Once I click that href link I'm calling `PrintIndex` method so in
   that action method again its calling to `Create_Brochure_PDF` method ,
   so I'm getting null object set in `Create_Brochure_PDF`

Comment: Are you sure you are having data in `newmodel` before adding to session

Comment: If you're using ExpressIIS when debugging, sessions are killed after each launch. Are you definitely hitting `Create_Brochure` *every time* before you hit `Create_Brochure_PDF`?

Comment: @RahulNikate Yeah , once I debug this I can see model values assign to  `IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel` in `Create_Brochure` method but then I can see `IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel` become `null` in `Create_Brochure_PDF` also

Comment: @Rob , yes , its orginal flow is `Create_Brochure` and then `Create_Brochure_PDF` I'm using IIS10

Comment: @Rob If I explain whole scenario this 1. `Create_Brochure` controller method has a view , 2. In that view I have href link to save that `Create_Brochure` view as PDF 3.Once I click that link I'm calling `PrintIndex` method so in that action method again its calling to `Create_Brochure_PDF` method , so I'm getting null object set in `Create_Brochure_PDF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue some times ago, So I came up with solution `ViewasPdf()` method in Rotativa library

You can directly call to once You click that href link but you have to create a View for this method that your going to generate as PDF

So here the steps

1. Create a Action for the View that your Going to Generate as PDF

   ```
   public ActionResult Create_Brochure_PDF()
   {

       IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> newmodel = Session["TemplateData"] as IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM>;

       IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> samplePDF = newmodel.Where(.... 

       rerurn View();
   ```

   }
2. Generate view for that Action method
3. Replace this line `rerurn View();` with following line in `Create_Brochure_PDF()` method

`return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("Create_Brochure_PDF") { FileName = "TestActionAsPdf.pdf" };`

4. Now call the `Create_Brochure_PDF()` method as follows in
   Create_Brochure view page

`<a href="@Url.Action("Create_Brochure_PDF", "Brochure")">Download ViewAsPdf</a>`